# Spring Boot: can't get API key into the docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, environment-variables

I created an spring boot application that makes API calls. I have been given an API key that I added to my system environment variables as API_KEY

At first, I had my urls as
*String uri = "http://api-site.com/.../key="+**System.getenv("API_KEY")**+"&..."*
and this works just fine when I run it locally.

However, when I build and run the image, I get 403 error.
My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM maven:3.5.4-jdk-8-alpine AS builder

COPY pom.xml pom.xml
COPY src/ src/

RUN mvn clean package

FROM openjdk:11 AS runner

**ENV API_KEY $API_KEY**

EXPOSE 8080

COPY --from=builder target/app-0.0.1.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "app.jar" ]
```

I'm guessing System.getenv("API_KEY") does not work in containers.
Is there a way to get it to work?

I've tried the other syntax for the environment variable in the Dockerfile: ENV API_KEY=${API_KEY}

I have also tried using application.properties but I have not been able to get that to work (this might need to be a whole other question). I can't even get test variables to print.
I have test.name=testname in applications.properties
In a class I have:

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AC {
    @Value("${test.name}")
    public String test;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

This just prints out null every time.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "*I'm guessing System.getenv("API_KEY") does not work in containers.*" - It does work. --- Why should `System.out.println(test)`print the environment variable `API_KEY`? Please [edit] the post and add your `application.properties`.

Comment: I strongly suggest to not hard-code the API Key as environment variable in the container image (for security reasons). We can always override/set environment variables in docker with `docker run -e "<ENV_VAR_NAME>=<value>" ...`

Comment: I got the same error, is it possible to pass in an environment varibale when I build the image?

Comment: Again: there is no reason why property `test.name` should be bound to environment variable `${API_KEY}`, at least none I can see. We normally bind properties to environment variables with the following syntax in `application.properties`: `test.name=${API_KEY:optional-default-value}`. This is why I asked you to post your `application.properties`.

Comment: It was literally just ```test.name=testName```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your dockerfile, do you try to take an env variable from the builder system into your docker file? if so this won't work (and doesn't make much sense to me). you better be using -e in your running command. also, you can always check inside if the variable is sourced or not using an interactive shell

Comment: Thank you! I will try that, I just saw this on sample Dockerfiles and assumed that's how it would work